# Run a program in Python's subprocess module, with required files from Terminal

Tags: python, subprocess

Is it feasible to run a program in Python's subprocess module, but with files from Terminal?

So I want to run the following program from within Python:

```
myProgram -a myArg
```

However, suppose that the above program requires the file `myFile` in the current directory, and it doesn't take the required file as an argument. So, if you run the above program in the directory where there is `myFile`, the program succeeds in processing. However, if you run it in the directory where there is NOT `myFile`, the execution fails.

And when I tried to execute the program from within Python's `subprocess.Popen()`, with `shell=True`, the program doesn't work and it looks like the reason it failed is the program wasn't able to read `myFile` when executed from within Python.

So, is there any way to run it successfully from within Python?

Answer (score 0):

```
subprocess.Popen('myProgram -a myArg', cwd='/folder/with_myFile/')
```

Similar Question: [Python specify popen working directory via argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685157/python-popen-working-directory-argument)

Comment: I also don't know why I have to specify the directory - I run the script where the script should be...

Comment: I am not sure, are you saying the `cwd` is NOT working for you?

Comment: It's irrelevant whether I specify `cwd` or not, since all of my Python program, "subprocessed" program, and `myFile` are located in the current directory. `cwd` has to be specified only when you change the directory before executing the "subprocessed" program, right?