# Run a setup.py from another Python script, path issue, installing in calling script dir?

Tags: python, subprocess, setup.py

First, I've found how to call a script from within an other script in Python, the call works perfectly well, but here's the problem I'm running into :

In order to easy-install my web-app (Bottle) on an another server, I packed inside a /redist rep, with mod_wsgi and PyMySQL source files. What I'm trying to achieve is a kind of "setup.py" file, that will launch the /mod_wsgi/setup.py install file and the same with the PyMySQL setup file.

Here's what I'm doing for PyMySQL for example :

```
subprocess.call("python3 ./redist/PyMySQL/setup.py install", shell=True)
```

The instalation runs fine, BUT, I end up with a `/build`, a `/dist` and a `/PyMySQL.egg-info` folders in my app directory, and when I'm trying to launch anything that imports PyMySQL, it told me that the module didn't exist.

If I manually install it (using my terminal I mean, like `cd /redist/PyMySQL/` and then `py3 setup.py install`), it works great, and the import will then work ...

Any idea ? Am I doing something wrong ?

By advance, thanks :)

Comment: I think this would solve your issue :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685157/python-specify-popen-working-directory-via-argument

Comment: Yeah, but, what workingdir should I use ? /usr/local/lib/pythonx.y ? / ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would solve your issue : [Python specify popen working directory via argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685157/python-specify-popen-working-directory-via-argument)

I suppose in the "./redist/PyMySQL/" directory could be used as parameter because it is where the setup.py is located

try this :

```
subprocess.Popen("py3 setup.py", cwd='/redist/PyMySQL/')
```

on my end this works :

```
subprocess.Popen(['py3','setup.py'], cwd='path-of-my-setup')
```

Comment: I ended up with this :
 `x = os.getcwd()
 install_path = ''.join(["",str(x),"/redist/PyMySQL/"])
 subprocess.Popen("%ssetup.py" %install_path, cwd="'%s'" %install_path)`
Not working

Comment: Hum, you are forgetting the python command, maybe that would help.

Comment: if I use this line : `subprocess.Popen("python3 %ssetup.py" %install_path, cwd="'%s'" %install_path)` (where install_path is the right path to the /PyMySQL folder, I got an error say that /var/www/AGS/redist/PyMySQL/setup.py doesn't exist (but it does !)

Comment: I updated the code in the answer, did you try it ? (note to put the correct dir in the cws ;) )

Comment: Ok and try the new code where 'path-of-my-setup' is your absolute path from root '/' to the setup.py file :=)

Comment: Ok, it's now working fine, thanks a lot ! I'm using `subprocess.Popen(args, cwd='%s' %working_dir)`
where `args` is : `args = ['%ssetup.py' %working_dir,'install']`

I was already using path from root (working_dir is `''.join(["",str(os.getcwd),"/redist/PyMySQL/"])`)

Comment: Actually, why do we need to run `setup.py` on the directory itself? is there any documentation that refer to this?

Comment: @joshuaH you might want to put your comment in the question of the topic itself :)