# Python: fatal: not a git repository Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set)

Tags: python, python-3.x, git, git-commit, python-3.8

When I run

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['git', 'add', '-A'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

I get this error

```
fatal: not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /media)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
```

But running

```
os.system('git add -A')
```

Does the job perfectly.

If you think the folder does not have a `.git` file,

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['ls', '-a'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

shows that it is already in the cwd.

Why `Popen` cannot stage the files, nor can it do the commit while `os.system` does both?

---

**Update:**

Here is my failed MWE

```
import subprocess
import os

cwd = os.getcwd()
proj_path = os.path.join(cwd, 'newproj')
os.makedirs(proj_path)
os.chdir(proj_path)
proc = subprocess.Popen(['git', 'init'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
proc = subprocess.Popen(['ls', '-a'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print(proc.stdout.read().decode('ascii'))
proc = subprocess.Popen(['git', 'add', '-A'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = proc.communicate()
if err:
    print('Error:\n', err.decode())
print(out.decode('ascii'))
```

output

```
.
..
.git

fatal: not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /media)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
```

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31766655/git-add-through-python-subprocess

Comment: @lesmana, if the cwd is not set, then how come `ls -a` works on the cwd?

Comment: That is ... odd. Do you have a [mcve]?

Comment: @torek, Added MWE.

Comment: i was not sure how it would help. the other question was similar in that git add did not work. it was a shot in the dark. i was not able to reproduce your problem and was baffled. this was before you added the minimal working example. now it is clear that it is a race condition. you have to communicate or wait for each subprocess.

Comment: @lesmana, no the questions are not the same. in the other question the problem was robustness of `git filter-branch` under network directories.

Comment: I was facing a similar problem - the same error message. It was due to attempts to run git commands without being in the git folder (I was in the parent one). `cd repodir` was the magic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My Python version is a little behind yours, but I was able to reproduce the problem, which is actually pretty simple:

```py
proc = subprocess.Popen(['git', 'init'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
proc = subprocess.Popen(['ls', '-a'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print(proc.stdout.read().decode('ascii'))
proc = subprocess.Popen(['git', 'add', '-A'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Note the lack of any calls to `proc.wait()` or similar.  This means we spin off a `git init` and *do not wait for it*.

Next, we run `ls -a`.  Here we do wait a little bit—long enough to read its output to EOF, which is actually relatively long as EOF only occurs because `ls -a` finishes—and meanwhile the `git init` is still running.  Depending on how fast `git init` is doing its work, we may or may not find the `.git` directory here.  If this takes long enough, the `git init` may also finish.  Fortunately the `git init` on my system is sufficiently slower than the `ls -a` that I see the same effect as you.  (Well, I found that the `.git` directory sometimes doesn't exist yet.)

Last, we run `git add -A`.  The `git init` may or may not still be running.  As it turns out, it *is* still running, and has not yet gotten far enough to establish the `.git` directory as a Git *repository*.  So `git add -A` complains, with the error you observed.

If we add `proc.wait()` right after the `git init`—ideally, we should check the return code, or simply use `subprocess.check_call` or `subprocess.run` here—the problem goes away.