# How can I change directory with Python pathlib

Tags: python, pathlib

What is the intended way to change directory using the Python `pathlib` [(Documentation)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) functionality?

Lets assume I create a `Path` object as follows:

```
from pathlib import Path
path = Path('/etc')
```

Currently I just know the following, but that seems to undermine the idea of `pathlib`.

```
import os
os.chdir(str(path))
```

Comment: changing the current directory is rarely a good idea anyway. Why do you need to change directory for?

Comment: There is a small bash script I want to rewrite in Python. That way I can handle errors more easily than calling an external bash script.

Comment: you don't have to use `pathlib` if you don't need it - `os.chdir('/etc')`

Comment: I feel like `pathlib` leads to more elegant code. But since `cd` is not elegant by any means, I might as well go with `os.chdir('/etc')`?

Comment: `pathlib` is module to work with paths, not to change directory.

Comment: @furas; tell that to the core devs.  See Path.read_bytes and Path.read_text.

Comment: Since `pathlib` doesn't offer functionality specifically for this, the question reduces to "how do I change directories?", where the `Path` instance simply *specifies* the directory (and tools like `os.chdir` already work with that specification). So this is a duplicate - and would really remain a duplicate if the functionality were added later, *because that would be a legitimate answer for the canonical too*.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Based on the comments I realized that `pathlib` does not help changing directories and that directory changes should be avoided if possible.

Since I needed to call bash scripts outside of Python from the correct directory, I opted for using a context manager for a cleaner way of changing directories similar to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/431747/911441):

```
import os
import contextlib
from pathlib import Path

@contextlib.contextmanager
def working_directory(path):
    """Changes working directory and returns to previous on exit."""
    prev_cwd = Path.cwd()
    os.chdir(path)
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        os.chdir(prev_cwd)
```

A good alternative is to use the `cwd` parameter of the `subprocess.Popen` class as in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1685166/911441).

If you are using Python <3.6 and `path` is actually a `pathlib.Path`, you need `str(path)` in the `chdir` statements.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! I'm testing a command line tool whose required parameters depend on the cwd, so I need to move the cwd around in order to test this functionality. However if I write it the naive way, then when a test fails it will throw an unexpected exception and the cwd doesn't get moved back, meaning that all future tests start with the wrong cwd and give useless errors. Using a context manager means I *know* it gets moved back! I think try-except-finally blocks are also valid, but writing a context manager is more reliable and saves code over multiple tests.

Answer (score 27):

In the Python 3.6 or above, `os.chdir()` can deal with `Path` object directly. In fact, the `Path` object can replace most `str` paths in standard libraries.

> os.**chdir**(path) Change the current working directory to path.
>
> This function can support specifying a file descriptor. The descriptor
>   must refer to an opened directory, not an open file.
>
> New in version 3.3: Added support for specifying path as a file
>   descriptor on some platforms.
>
> Changed in version 3.6: Accepts a [path-like object](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-path-like-object).

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

path = Path('/etc')
os.chdir(path)
```

This may help in the future projects which do not have to be compatible with 3.5 or below.

Comment: Yes, that is very nice indeed. I hope the Python community either accepts `pathlib.Path` anywhere or abandons it altogether.

Comment: @Lukas: I really want to like it, but currently I can't accept it.  And since it's been three years since your comment, I suspect I can't ever… and os.path will stay anyway. I could and would accept it if it could replace os.path completely.  Therein lies the rub.  For me at least.

Comment: Naturally, **this should be the accepted answer.** Yes, it'd be preferable for API orthogonality if a hypothetical full-fledged `pathlib.Path.chdir()` method existed – but this is the next best thing. Let's not let the perfect become the enemy of the good *yet again.*

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using [a third-party library](https://github.com/jaraco/path):

`$ pip install path`

then:

```
from path import Path

with Path("somewhere"):
    # current working directory is now `somewhere`
    ...
# current working directory is restored to its original value.
```

or if you want to do it without the [context manager](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers):

```
Path("somewhere").cd()
# current working directory is now changed to `somewhere`
```

Comment: Just to be perfectly clear, this is not the standard library pathlib.  Using   with pathlib.Path('x') does not change directory.