# Issues running python file on Pycharm (Python 3.8)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I wrote a single python file that should create a csv file in the local directory when executed. The python file does not create a csv file in the local directory, even though execution completes successfully. My code and output screenshot are included below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import os
def web_scraper(self):
    os.chdir(r"/Users/bsulin/PycharmProjects/StockNewsWebScraper/")

    print("Hi print")

    return("Hi return")
```

[image: Pycharm Project Structure as Source Folder]

[image: Code Output]

Comment: It seems that your question is just "[how to] create a csv file in the local directory". There is no need for web scraping, nor most of the other malformed code, to this question. Please reduce your code to a *minimal* reproducible example, both to help us understand and answer your question, and to help you realise potential errors yourself. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for details.

Comment: Ok thanks, I've updated my question with your feedback.

Comment: That's not what I requested. You have also removed the ``csv`` writing code. Do you actually *call* ``web_scraper``, though?

Comment: It works now! I think I needed to remove the function from the class. So doesn't look like web_scraper function was being called.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I change directory with Python pathlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41742317/how-can-i-change-directory-with-python-pathlib)

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely saving it somewhere you're not expecting due to a current working directory (cwd) issue.

Either change the current working directory in PyCharm as per [PyCharm current working directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34304044/pycharm-current-working-directory), or explicitly change it with code:

```py
import os # put these lines at the top of your script
os.chdir(r"/Users/bsulin/PycharmProjects/StockNewsWebScraper/")
```

Comment: I tried both of those methods (updated question with details), and it's still not working. Won't even print or return my "Hi" strings.

Comment: That's very strange. Try creating a new project in PyCharm and just put `print("test")`, see if that works.

Comment: It works now! I think I needed to remove the function from the class.

Comment: Oh I think what happened was that you created the function `web_scraper`, but you never called it, so it was never executed.