# Execute batch file in different directory

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a a file structure like the following (Windows):

```
D:\
    dir_1\
        batch_1.bat
        dir_1a\
            batch_2.bat
    dir_2\
        main.py
```

For the sake of this question, `batch_1.bat` simply calls `batch_2.bat`, and looks like:

```
cd dir_1a
start batch_2.bat %*
```

Opening `batch_1.bat` from a command prompt indeed opens `batch_2.bat` as it's supposed to, and from there on, everything is golden.

Now I want my Python file, `D:\dir_2\main.py`, to spawn a new process which starts `batch_1.bat`, which in turn should start `batch_2.bat`. So I figured the following Python code should work:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen(['cd "D:/dir_1"', "start batch_1.bat"], shell=True)
```

This results in "The system cannot find the path specified" being printed to my Python console. (No error is raised, of course.) This is due to the first command. I get the same result even if I cut it down to:

```
subprocess.Popen(['cd "D:/"'], shell=True)
```

I also tried starting the batch file directly, like so:

```
subprocess.Popen("start D:/dir_1/batch_1.bat", shell=True)
```

For reasons that I don't entirely get, this seems to just open a windows command prompt, *in `dir_2`*.

If I forego the `start` part of this command, then my Python process is going to end up waiting for `batch_1` to finish, which I don't want. But it does get a little further:

```
subprocess.Popen("D:/dir_1/batch_1.bat", shell=True)
```

This results in `batch_1.bat` successfully executing... in `dir_2`, the directory of the Python script, rather than the directory of `batch_1.bat`, which results in it not being able to find `dir_1a\` and hence, `batch_2.bat` is not executed at all.

I am left highly confused. What am I doing wrong, and what should I be doing instead?

Comment: Did you try `subprocess.Popen(r'start D:\dir_1\batch_1.bat', shell=True, cwd=r'd:\dir_1')` ?

Comment: using `&&` should work : `Popen('cd D:/dir_1/ && start batch_1.bat', shell = True)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is answered here: [Python specify popen working directory via argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685157/python-specify-popen-working-directory-via-argument)

In a nutshell, just pass an optional cwd argument to `Popen`:

```
subprocess.Popen(["batch_1.bat"], shell=True, cwd=r'd:\<your path>\dir1')
```