# Python Popen doesn't recognize scrapy when python script is run as systemd service

Tags: python, scrapy, virtualenv, popen, systemd

I have a python script `main.py` that needs to start the [scrapy](https://scrapy.org/) executable, so I use Popen to do that (using `subprocess.call()` has same result). To simplify things I just run the help argument of scrapy.

```
import subprocess
...
p = subprocess.Popen(['scrapy', '-h'])
```

The script needs to be run inside a vitualenv which has scrapy installed on it. When I activate the virtualenv and run the script as `python main.py` the command `scrapy -h` is executed as expected.

Now, I need this script to be run as a systemd service. I have created the systemd unit for the script as follows:

```
[Unit]
Description=Scrapy test
After=network.target

[Service]
User={{ scrapy_user }}
WorkingDirectory={{ test_path }}
ExecStart={{ virtualenv_path }}/bin/python {{ test_path }}/main.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I enable and start the service with `sudo systemctl start scrapy-test` the code runs normally until `p = subprocess.Popen(['scrapy', '-h'])` when I get an exception raised

```
File "{{ test_path }}/main.py", line 52, in launch_spider
   p = subprocess.Popen(['scrapy', '-h'])
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
   errread, errwrite)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
   raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I have also tried to change the working directory by adding `os.chdir('{{ virtualenv_path }}/bin')` just before `Popen`, but I get the exact same exception. I am sure the script is run through the virtualenv because (1) it is set so in the `ExecStart` attribute and (2) the script would raise exceptions earlier when importing modules that are not installed in the system's python.

Comment: I have the same problem, but in my case your solution does not work, as it is a third-party lib (pygatt) which calls hcitool or gatttool.

Comment: Could you move your answer from an edit in your question to a proper, accepted response?

Answer (score 1):

You must [specify the current working directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1685166/939364) on your call to `Popen` to ensure that `scrapy` is executed from the right directory.

Answer (score 0):

The clue is here:

```
ExecStart={{ virtualenv_path }}/bin/python {{ test_path }}/main.py
```

The `scrapy` command is on `$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin`, which is not on the `systemd` `$PATH`.

You could try:

```
import os
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(['%s/bin/scrapy' % os.environ['VIRTUAL_ENV'], '-h'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Another issue you may encounter later, you may want to make python to wait for the end of subprocess run with **p.wait()**:

```
import os
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(['%s/bin/scrapy' % os.environ['VIRTUAL_ENV'], '-h'])
p.wait()
```

Otherwise systemctl may terminate your processes too early.