# Python subprocess fails although it works in the command line

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to run an R script from Python. The Rscript `train.R` is in the same folder as the Jupyter Notebook. The working directory is set to that folder.

```py
import subprocess
try:
    subprocess.check_call(['Rscript', 'train.R'], shell=False)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    print(e.output)
    print(e.returncode)
    print(e)
    print(e.stderr)
```

I am getting a CalledProcessError:

```
None
1
Command '['Rscript', 'train.R']' returned non-zero exit status 1
None
```

I tried to set the argument `shell=True` and I tried to set the argument`cwd=os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath("train.R"))` as mentioned [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685157/how-can-i-specify-working-directory-for-popen)

The command `Rscript train.R` works just fine if I open a console in the folder.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does the `stderr` reveal? It's attached to the exception.

Comment: @a_guest It holds None

Comment: It is `None` because you don't capture neither stdout nor stderr. You should use `subprocess.run(..., capture_output=True)` instead. See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend you make use of `Popen` instead

```
import subprocess
try:
    pro = subprocess.Popen(['Rscript', 'train.R'], shell=False)

    stdout, stderr = pro.communicate()

    print(stdout)
    print(stderr)
```

With this you should be able to get your error or output values from the subprocess

Comment: Just wanted to add... If for some reason you aren't getting the expected stdout and stderr output from your process, you may need to also include the 'subprocess.PIPE' parameter in your Popen constructor. ie pro = subprocess.Popen(['Rscript', 'train.R'], shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE )