# Failure to run shell script via subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, python-3.x, singer-io

I am trying to a script `run.sh` using python `subprocess`

The script creates a `csv file` and a `state.json` file

This is the script(works fine when i run it from terminal) :

```
#!/bin/bash
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/home/anti/Documents/bq_s3/BQ/bin/client_secret.json"

/home/anti/Documents/bq_s3/BQ/bin/tap-bigquery -c /home/anti/Documents/bq_s3/BQ/bin/tap_config.json --catalog /home/anti/Documents/bq_s3/BQ/bin/catalog.json --start_datetime '2013-01-01T00:00:00Z' --end_datetime '2013-01-02T00:00:00Z' | /home/anti/Documents/bq_s3/targetcsv/targetcsv/bin/target-csv --config /home/anti/Documents/bq_s3/targetcsv/targetcsv/bin/target_config.json > /home/anti/Documents/bq_s3/state.json
```

But when i try to run the same from python, it shows the correct output , but doesnt create `csv file` and a `state.json` file

This is the python code

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import subprocess   
from ast import literal_eval
import io
import os
from subprocess import call

shellscript = subprocess.Popen(["/home/anti/Documents/bq_s3/run.sh"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
shellscript.wait()
print (shellscript.returncode)
```

Output

```
INFO Sending version information to singer.io. To disable sending anonymous usage data, set the config parameter "disable_collection" to true
INFO Running query:
    SELECT start_date,trip_seconds,trip_miles FROM `testbq-305217.test_1.tablename` WHERE 1=1 AND datetime '2013-01-01 00:00:00.000000' <= CAST(start_date as datetime) AND CAST(start_date as datetime) < datetime '2013-01-02 00:00:00.000000' ORDER BY start_date LIMIT 100
INFO METRIC: {"type": "counter", "metric": "record_count", "value": 1, "tags": {"endpoint": "test_bq"}}
INFO Syncing stream:test_bq
0
```

The return code is 0, the program works but the `csv` and `json` files are not being created when ran from python.

I have given necessary permission `chmod u+rx run.sh` to the script too.

Comment: What do you see when turning on `set -x`?

Comment: where do i do that ? inside `Popen` ?

Comment: Found the issue, the files are getting created at `home` directory and not the cwd. How do i change the output path ?

Comment: You can either inside your script do an explicit `set -x`, or modify your `Popen` so that it effectively runs the command `bash -x run.sh` instead of simply `run.sh`.

Comment: I suggest that you ask this in a new question, since this is not related anymore to Python or bash, but to the correct usage of `target-csv`. As such, this question should go to [su] instead of [so].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned in the comments since the issue was that current working directory is not set properly pass `cwd` param to the `subprocess.Popen`.  Better yet, replace `subprocess.Popen()` with a higher-level function, as recommended in its documentation.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import subprocess   

shellscript = subprocess.call(["/home/anti/Documents/bq_s3/run.sh"], cwd=YOUR_WORKING_DIR)
print(shellscript)
```

Comment: The issue is that the output files are getting created at home directory and not the `cwd`. The output path needs to be changed to `cwd`, anyway i can do that in the script ?

Comment: you can  actually pass the `cwd` to subprocess.Popen

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1685166/8029019

Comment: that worked man..thanks ..edit your answer so that i can accept it