# Latex to pdf with Pyhton, pdf storing location change

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdflatex

I'm trying to create a pdf file from a latex file (some/directory/something.tex). It works but the pdf is not stored in the same directory as the latex File. After all it is stored in the directory where I execute the python script. Where can I change the location for saving  the pdf?

`proc = subprocess.Popen(['pdflatex', some/directory/something.tex])`
`proc.communicate()`

Comment: [This question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685157/how-can-i-specify-working-directory-for-popen) will probably help. You either need to specify the directory/file to pdflatex or change your working directory.

Comment: Don't specify an latex output directory, this will cause much more problems with latex than it solves. Either switch into the folder of your tex file or have a look at https://github.com/reitzig/ltx2any